# Page mask before Page_Load

Tags: asp.net

I need to apply page masking to every page in the website. Every page will be masked until page_load is complete.

I tried to put this in master page:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress" runat="server"  DynamicLayout="false"  >
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="Progress">Loading...</div>
        <div id="bgDiv"></div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

But it won't work. To test it I gave a delay on master's page_load. But mask was not applied. Can anybody help?

Comment: by Page Mask, you mean a full page fade out style with a loading image ?

Comment: Yes. I want to put transparent screen until page_load is complete.

Comment: Suggestion: Read ASP.NET page Life Cycle MSDN article. You have to use  JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this can be done using javascript and css, and not with code behind. So here is an example how you can do it:

### Page Mask

Firs the code that make that trick to the page. Lets say that you select a way that make the page looks non clickable, fade out.

This can be done with a div and a css. There are many examples on the internet that do that, here is one sample code for  [full page overlay](http://library.creativecow.net/articles/chaffin_abraham/full-page-overlay.php)

```
<style>
#displaybox {
    z-index: 10000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /*older IE*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
    -moz-opacity: .50; /*older Mozilla*/
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;   /*older Safari*/
    opacity: 0.5;   /*supported by current Mozilla, Safari, and Opera*/
    background-color:#000000;
    position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
```

### Synchronous Page Load / or post back

You set the fade out div right after the body on the html page part, and make a flush() so it will appear right away, as:

```
<div id="FadeOutBox" ></div><%Response.Flush(); %>
```

and on the bottom of the page you remove it using javascript, or overight the css style, as:

```
<script>document.getElementById('FadeOutBox').style.display = "none";</script>
```

### Asynchronous / UpdatePanel call

If you have an update panel, then you need to capture the events that Update Panel fires and make this div visible or not each time, as:

```
<script>
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        // Show the mask
        document.getElementById('FadeOutBox').style.display = "block";
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        // Hide it
        document.getElementById('FadeOutBox').style.display = "none";
    }

</script>
```

### Open the Page Mask right away on Post Back

You can even open the page mask on post back, before the page load, and have it and after the page load. You do that using this code behind to capture the submit:

```
if (Page.EnableEventValidation)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"]))
    {
        Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"] = "return ShowWait();";
    }
}
```

and on javascript part:

```
function ShowWait()
{
   document.getElementById('FadeOutBox').style.display = "block";
   return true; 
}
```